# Regex for wildcard character search

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for javascript regex which will start with alphabets only and may end with % ie % is optional.I referred http://grainge.org/pages/authoring/regex/regular_expressions.htm
https://ryanstutorials.net/regular-expressions-tutorial/regular-expressions-basics.php & w3 schools.
So far i used [a-zA-ZÀ-ž]%?$ where it is accepting characters starting with alphabets but it is accepting multiple % after other alphabets.
Valid : abc% (starting with alphabets ending with optional %)
Invalid : abc%xyz%xyz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want to match the whole string so you have to anchor the beginning of string too. Something like `^[a-zA-ZÀ-ž]+%?$` should work. (Note: this will fail if you have non alphabet chars in the string)

Comment: That means i forgot to use + before %?,anyways thanks a ton.

Comment: The + is a quantificator and indicates one or more character(s) from the set in square brackets (in this case). As you wrote it, it would match strings like 'a%' or 'b' at end of string (just one char)